# Parsing XML Truncates File Path

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception

I am receiving a FileNotFoundException with the following code:

```
File dataFile = new File("\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\PATH\TO\FILE.xml");

if(dataFile.isFile())
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    // Printing out File displays full path
    Document doc = db.parse(dataFile);
}
```

This is resulting in a FileNotFoundException: \PATH\TO\FILE.xml. It appears to have truncated the IP address out of the path. I have checked that the path name does not include any spaces and if I print out the path of the File object before parsing, the full path is displayed. Any ideas?

I am running Java 1.5_14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
File dataFile = new File("\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\PATH\TO\FILE.xml");
```

to

```
File dataFile = new File("\\\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\\PATH\\TO\\FILE.xml");
```

remember that in Java, \ escapes the next character...

**Edit**: Assuming that you are getting a FNFE from the line:

```
Document doc = db.parse(dataFile);
```

then it means that the `datafile.isFile()` is passing, and so the file should exist. Just for testing purposes, you might want to try changing that to:

```
Document doc = db.parse(dataFile.toURI().toString());
```

or

```
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new FileReader(dataFile)));
```

And see what happens.

Comment: It is throwing a FileNotFoundException. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Ben Cool, I have removed that question from my answer ;-)

Comment: both of your suggestions worked. I ended up using the URI. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a complete url with a scheme instead of unc path.

file://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/path/to/file.xml